# Loop through result from a .NET web service call in php

Tags: php, asp.net, web-services, wsdl

I'm working on getting results form a .net web service with a method that returns a generic list. Using var_dump in the php page (which is calling the .net method using WSDL), I was able to see the following is returned from the .net web service:

```
object(stdClass)#4 (1) { 
    ["testClass"]=> array(2) { 
        [0]=> object(stdClass)#5 (2) { 
            ["City"]=> string(7) "Hello_1" 
            ["State"]=> string(8) "World!_1" 
        } 
        [1]=> object(stdClass)#6 (2) { 
            ["City"]=> string(7) "Hello_2" 
            ["State"]=> string(8) "World!_2" 
        } 
    }
}
```

This might be a silly question but I'm stuck in procesing (looping through) this result in php? Do I have to create the class "testClass" in php also?

Here is the .net webservice code

```
public class testClass
    {
        public string City;
        public string State;
    }

[WebMethod]
public List<testClass> testAspMethod(string Param1, string Param2) 
{
    List<testClass> l = new List<testClass>();

    l.Add(new testClass { City = Param1 + "_1", State = Param2 + "_1" });
    l.Add(new testClass { City = Param1 + "_2", State = Param2 + "_2" });

    return l;
}
```

Here is the php code that calls this .net web service

$client = new SoapClient("http://testURL/MyTestService.asmx?WSDL");

```
$params->Param1 = 'Hello'; 
$params->Param2 = 'World!';

$result = $client->testAspMethod($params)->testAspMethodResult;

var_dump($result);
```

How can I loop through the results in php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work regardless of the number of items returned. If you don't do the array check like I have here, your code will produce unexpected results. If the webservice returns only a single item, it won't return an array. Instead it will actually put the object directly in `$result->testClass`, e.g. `$result->testClass->City` not `$result->testClass[0]->City` as you might expect.

```
// here we make sure we have an array, even if there's just one item in it
if(is_array($result->testClass))
{
    $result = $result->testClass;
}
else
{
    $result = array($result->testClass);
}

foreach($result as $item)
{
    echo 'City: ' . $item->City . '<br />';
    echo 'State: ' . $item->State . '<br />';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know the name that's being returned (testClass, in this case), you can ...

```
foreach($result->testClass as $key => $obj){
    echo "Key: $key\n";
    echo $obj->City . "\n";
    echo $obj->State . "\n";
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work if the webservice returns a single object instead of multiple.